# How to set SSH key file to different directory?

Tags: debian, ssh, key-authentication

Using Debian 8.

I need a myuser user, which should have no password, just key file based SSH login.

My /etc/passwd contains the following:

```
myuser:x:11:11:myuser:/my/specific/path:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

How can I set SSH private key file to a different directory?

I tried to add a specific path to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2 /my/specific/path/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

but doesn't authenticate when trying to login to SSH with myuser username.

But I get:

```
ssh myuser@192.168.0.1
myuser@192.168.0.1's password:
```

**EDIT1:**
The .ssh dir permission:

```
ls -la /my/specific/path
drwx------ 2 myuser myuser    4096 Apr 23  2018 .ssh
```

The authorized_keys file permission:

```
ls -la /my/specific/path/.ssh
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser  101 Jun 15 19:51 authorized_keys
```

But still can not login.
How to fix?

Comment: The most likely cause is permissions. You probably don't need to change `AuthorizedKeysFile` at all. Try with `ssh -vv myuser@192.168.0.1` and also watch the log file that sshd writes to (`journalctl -f -u sshd` for a systemd system).

Comment: You don't need to change the `sshd` configuration at all. The `/my/specific/path/.ssh/authorized_keys` is already searched since it's the default `.ssh` directory in the user's home directory (in fact, changing the config would make the SSH daemon check that file for _every_ user that connects) Just make sure that the file itself has the correct permissions (`rw` for owner only).

Comment: N.B. Even if you authenticate, you're not going to be able to open an ssh session with `/usr/sbin/nologin` as your login shell (with the exception of SFTP, _if_ the server is configured properly).

Comment: Edited question. Added permission info. What should I use instead of  /usr/sbin/nologin?

Comment: @klor Use any valid login shell (see `/etc/shells`).

Comment: As @Kusalananda has said, any valid login shell.  BUT you can then lock that account. This will still permit SSH via keys but the user couldn't sit down at the machine and login using a password. Use `usermod --lock <user>`.

Comment: I want to use that user as backup account, which can be only accessed by the backup software using public key only.